# How can I check my Mail?

Tags: borderlands-3

Apparently I've recieved a couple of mail from different weapon manufacturers but I can't find it anywhere. I have a mail icon below the mini-map but I can't seem to find a mail tab in my echo device and even on the Quick-Change Station there's nothing.

How do I check my mail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mail menu option is hidden in the **Social tab** in the **main menu** (Esc on PC).

The fourth tab will include all your mail from manufacturers, NPCs and promotions (Shift-Codes, special editions etc).

Additionally you will be able to send items to your friends in this menu.

Answer (score 5):

You can directly press **F4** (on PC) to access to your mails in-game.

Your mail often contains great weapons which are gift from the companies.